# Webpage not indexed by google because of unknown host DNS error

Tags: google-search-console

I have hosted a site on github and encounter the following error in the Google Search Console URL inspection section.

[image]

The custom domain I'm using was purchased through Google Domains. How can I enable google indexing of my site?

Below is information about my DNS setup that might be helpful.

[image]

Below is the updated DNS setup.

[image]

Comment: Is your site up now?  Was it down or having problems on Feb 17th?  How long has it been since you first hosted the site?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller good point, screenshot is from a previous data, but it still looks the same for today. And I hosted the site on Feb 1.

Comment: You probably just need to give it more time.  You need to give Google 2 weeks to see any changes you make.  New sites often need 6 months.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, I would agree that you need to wait for more time for Google to index your page, but doesn't the error indicate a DNS or problem other than Google's indexing bot?

Comment: Could be.  @TheNightman can you [edit] your question to add details about your DNS setup?  Especially things like NS, A, and CNAME records and who's services you are using for DNS hosting.

Comment: My advice is to make sure both the `www` and non-`www` versions of your website are working properly (try out both versions in your web browser). For a proper website setup, you should be able to reach your website by typing in either version, because the non-canonical version should redirect you to the canonical version. If one of the versions shows an error in your web browser, you've got a DNS issue to be fixed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I added some DNS information, hopefully that is sufficiently descriptive. And both www and non-www versions appear to work properly.

Comment: You have some problems there.  Your site doesn't work without `www`.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJOZ2.png

Comment: @StephenOstermiller hmm this is strange, do i have my `CNAME` entries incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of your DNS records, only one of them doing you any good. Keep this one for sure:

- `CNAME www.example.com`

your TXT DNS record is not relevant for directing visitors to your site. It looks like it is used for HTTPS certificate generation.  I wouldn't touch it either.

Your other three records are not good and should be removed:

- `HTTPS example.com` -- `HTTPS` DNS records are only in a draft specification and should not be used.  You should remove this record.
- `CNAME https://.example.com` -- CNAME records should never contain `https://` as part of the host name.  You should remove this record.
- `CNAME https://www.example.com` -- CNAME records should never contain `https://` as part of the host name.  You should remove this record.

You need to add the following record:

- **Type**: `A`
- **Hostname**: `example.com` (use your real domain name, without `www.` and without `https://`)
- **Values** (These come from Github's documentation):

  ```
  185.199.108.153
  185.199.109.153
  185.199.110.153
  185.199.111.153
  ```

See [GitHub's documentation about the apex of the domain for details](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain)